# Error in Custom Refreshing JWT Token Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I used the simpleJWT in Django. The login works fine, however I want to implement a view for the refresh toke. So I get in the request body the access and refresh tokens, I check if the access token is still valid, and if its not then I generate a new one.

However this implementation does not seem to work. (testing it with postman with given tokens it requests for the users details)

serializers.py

```
class RefreshSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    accessToken = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    refreshToken = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
```

views.py

```
class TokenRefreshView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request):
        received_json_data = request.data
        serializer = RefreshSerializer(data=received_json_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            accessToken = received_json_data['accessToken']
            refreshToken = received_json_data['refreshToken']
            if (rest_framework_simplejwt.views.token_verify(accessToken).status_code != 200):
                user = rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication.get_user(accessToken)
                refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
                newaccesstoken = str(refresh.access_token)
                return JsonResponse({
                    'accessToken': newaccesstoken
                }, status=200)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({
                    'message': 'Token still valid',
                }, status=403)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message': serializer.errors}, status=400)
```

Comment: why you are doing this? django-rest-framework-simplejwt has this feature already

Comment: On simplejwt documentation you can find an example of how to use the default refresh route without having to re-implement it: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation

Comment: I want to change the form of the request data and the response as I indicate in my implementation. Is there a way to do this using the default implementation?

Comment: Also in the default implementation, everytime we hit the refresh endpoint we get a new access token, but I want this to be done only if the previous has expired